# Difference between -c:v and -vcodec, and -c:a and -acodec?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there's a difference between these two commands?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mkv

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no difference. If you check [the manual](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html):

```
-vcodec codec (output)
Set the video codec. This is an alias for -codec:v.
```

And of course `-codec` is the same as `-c`.

```
-c[:stream_specifier] codec (input/output,per-stream)
-codec[:stream_specifier] codec (input/output,per-stream)
```

However, I would encourage people to use the `-codec`/`-c` version, since it makes use of [stream specifiers](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Stream-specifiers) (`:v`, `:a`, `:s`), which are also used in filtergraphs or stream mapping.

Comment: Just so I don't make bad assumptions - does this mean that `-c:a` means `audio stream`, `-c:v` means `video stream`, etc?

Comment: @aggregate1166877 Yes, that's right.